# Use of footnote causes unrelated errors

Tags: packages, footnotes, compilation-error

My code only has harmless warnings (overfull hbox etc.), but as soon as I enter a footnote like `\footnote{foobar}`, I receive errors for completely unrelated things such as `Too many math alphabets used in version normal.`  or `Use of \reserved@a doesn't match its definition. \reserved@b ->\relax`   that I do not get without the footnote and the code does not compile successfully. I suspect it has something to do with the packages I load.

----------------------- UPDATE -----------------------

I have tried to create a minimal working example of the problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, a4paper]{report}


\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\RequirePackage{algorithm}
\RequirePackage{algpseudocode}
\RequirePackage{url}
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{erewhon}
\RequirePackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\let\mathcal\undefined
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\RequirePackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\RequirePackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\bmmax{0}
\RequirePackage{bm}
\RequirePackage{scalerel, stackengine}



                    

\begin{document}


\begingroup 
\addtolength{\jot}{.5em}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \mathbf{X}  &\; = \;  \mathbf{B} &\mathbf{N} \mathfrak{G} \bm{\gamma} \; \sim \; \mathcal{N}(0, \; \sigma^2 I_{d \times d}) \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\endgroup

where $\bm{\gamma}$

\begingroup 
\addtolength{\jot}{.5em}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    X  &\; = \leftarrow \;  N \mathcal{N}\mathcal{N}\bm{\beta} \bm{\beta}\bm{\beta}\qquad &N \; \sim \; \mathcal{N}(3, \; \sigma^2) \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\endgroup

\footnote{foobar}


\end{document}
```

Here, I get the same errors, but this time independent of whether I add a footnote or not. Hence, I believe the footnote is only a "trigger" for a problem that seem to be ignored otherwise in my full document.

----------------------- SOLUTION -----------------------

The problem is now solved. The problem was

```
\let\mathcal\undefined
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
```

(I like the mathdesign font, but not the `\mathcal` as defined there). Replacing the two lines above by

```
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{normal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
```

as suggested by Ulrike Fischer made everything work again, with the footnote and changed font to the desired `\mathcal`.

Comment: Try to remove `\RequirePackage{footnote}`.

Comment: I have already tried that to no avail.

Comment: make a small but complete example that demonstrates the error.  Unrelated: but don't use the ae package, that is obsolete since 20 years.

Comment: I have updated the question according to your suggestion.

Comment: Seem to be package order problems. Put `bm`, `mathtools` before redefining `\mathcal` because `amsmath` defines `\mathcal` (and no need to load `amsmath` because `mathtools` auto loads it). Additionally, `\renewcommand{\bmmax}` is needed.

Comment: you are confusing LaTeX with your `\let\mathcal\undefined`. mathdesign has setup a normal version for mathcal, and now you are undefining a part of the font setup. Try with `\SetMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{normal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}` instead.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This works for me! Thank you so much!